# Uploading documents via webservice slows down

Tags: web-services, migration, crawling

I am trying to upload a large number (100k+) of documents to a document library in SharePoint. The first few 1000 documents are fairly quick (0.2 sec/doc), however now that the migration is running some time (i'm at 20k) the migration slows down more and more (currently 1.3 sec/doc).

This is probably due to indexes in the SharePoint database that need to be rebuild every time. Is that correct? If so, is it possible to postpone indexing until after the migration for this library? If not, what might be the cause and a possible sollutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it looks to be a database throttling problem. We've created a new site collection with a seperate database attached for the library.